# CSS Bug: Columns in Mat-Table are sticky, but when I scroll border-right is not displayed

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, mat-table

when I scroll right my border-right becomes white and there are gaps. I have already tried everything, but I cannot find the error. Can you please help me?

[image: DataTable]

[image: Console]

Comment: any code that shows that problem?

Comment: i have fixed this problem :)